# Rendered Json Mixed with SQL

Tags: sql, json, grails

I can't really tell what happened and can't remember if I had upgraded `2.2.1` to `2.2.2`(my project is `2.2.2`), plus It was fine like 2-3 weeks ago, but I think that one of the reason that messed my whole JSON was from upgrade? (I don't know how to downgrade), but I don't want to mess any fonts in my project.

Anyway, when I call an `controller/action`, It render as `JSON`, but take a look at my piece of `JSON`:

Repeat this like `100x`.

```
{"_ref":"../../../..","class":"proj.State"},"stateId":1,"normalizedName":"Something","capital":false,"name":"Something"},"state":1},{"attached":true,"capital":false,"errors":{"errors":[]},"handler":    
{"class":"org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.proxy.GroovyAwareJavassistLazyInitializer","entityName":"proj.City","identifier":1,"implementation":
{"_ref":"../../../../../..","class":"proj.City"},"persistentClass":"proj.City","readOnly":false,"readOnlySettingAvailable":true,"session":{"JDBCContext":        
{"class":"org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext","connectionManager":{"aggressiveRelease":false,"autoCommit":true,"batcher":    
{"class":"org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher"},"class":"org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager","connection":{"autoCommit":true,"catalog":"DEVDB","class":"com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24"
```

And in my `grails-app/conf/spring/` contains my 2 `SQL` and I don't know why they come up with my `JSON` together, It didn't happened before.

What the cause could be?

Comment: First, why do you have sql in `grails-app/conf/spring/`? Second, What were you doing in the controller to render the json? Paste the rendering part.

Comment: Well, for now I dont have the code here, but simply was working before... like render x as JSON. my sql file are just load the some data, state, city, country.

Comment: I've been researching bit more, and It getting too my domains, ofc with SQL.

Comment: Found the problem, It was reflection, from address: company.address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflection from domains, found that he keeping searching all domain from the properties address: company.address and render this as json and give me all the crap.